# pagination ceiling an array using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm new in PDO and now i'm facing this

> Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

in mysql_ (old way) it work just fine to set to divide limit with rows, but it won't work with PDO,

this is the old way

limit is 4 start from 0, the database is more than 100 to count, the logic just fine

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` LIMIT $start, $limit");
$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles`"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
```

and with the PDO (new way they said)

```
$query=$db -> query("SELECT * FROM `articles` LIMIT $start, $limit");
$rows=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
```

and i get the error msg, any clues?

Comment: beside other things, in old mysql you were running 2 queries, while with PDO only one. So, it's not PDO but inaccurate transition.you need to pay more attention to the code you write. banging together few random lines and then asking strangers to fix it for you is not the way to go.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thx pro programmer

Comment: As a hint to improve the form of your question, it would be good if you mark the place the error message points to.

Comment: @Philipp ok phil, thx :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your mysql_-example you are explicitly fetching the rowcount of a query.

In your PDO implementation you are only fetching one result from the resultset your query returned. You could do something like this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` LIMIT $start, $limit");
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = ceil(count($rows)/$limit);
```

edit: If it is only about counting the rows you should to so in the db.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT count(*) AS rowcount FROM `articles` LIMIT $start, $limit");
$rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = ceil($rows['rowcount']/$limit);
```

Comment: brilliant, but im still a bit confuse with count, if im only fetching one result then how about something with ['count']??

Comment: I changed your `$query->fetch()` to `$query->fetchAll();` This way you will receive the whole resultset into $rows and as it is an array you can simply use php's count() on it. Have to note though, if this query only about counting the resultset it would indeed be better, performancewise and by semantic, to just directly select the count in mysql and return it.

Comment: he is a pro, dont mind him phillipp. what's the problem for asking something new, and kindly answer the question :/